# How do I present a jQuery result for a certain calculation as 'Not Available' instead of displaying £0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any time the `property_value` is less that `80,000` for the assisted, I want it to display 'Not Available' instead of showing `0` as at does the moment. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```js
var property_value = removeCommas(document.getElementById("fldPropertyValue").value);
property_value = formatAmount(property_value);
if (property_value.length == 2 || property_value.length == 3) {
  property_value = property_value + "000";
}

var percentage = 0.85;
var AssistedTotal;
var equity = 0;

var cashoffer, cashofferperentage;
var cashadvance, cashadvanceperentage;
var assisted, assistedpercentage;
var upfront;

if (property_value >= 0 && property_value <= 80000) {
  cashofferperentage = 0.75;
  assistedpercentage = 0.00;
  cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
} else if (property_value >= 80001 && property_value <= 150000) {
  cashofferperentage = 0.79;
  assistedpercentage = 0.85;
  cashadvanceperentage = 0.12;
} else if (property_value >= 150001 && property_value <= 400000) {
  cashofferperentage = 0.80;
  assistedpercentage = 0.85;
  cashadvanceperentage = 0.12;
} else if (property_value >= 400001 && property_value <= 750000) {
  cashofferperentage = 0.79;
  assistedpercentage = 0.83;
  cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
} else if (property_value >= 750001) {
  cashofferperentage = 0.75;
  assistedpercentage = 0.80;
  cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
}

cashoffer = property_value * cashofferperentage;
assisted = property_value * assistedpercentage;
```

Full code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {



        jQuery("#button3").click(function() {
            /*if(jQuery("#houseno").val()=="")
            {
                alert("Please provide house number");
                jQuery("#houseno").focus();
                return false;
            }*/
            if (jQuery("#pnumber").val() == "") {
                alert("Please provide house number");
                jQuery("#pnumber").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(jQuery("#pnumber").val())) {
                alert("Please enter contact number e.g.07000123456 with no spaces.");
                jQuery("#pnumber").focus();
                jQueryflag = false;
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#pnumber").val().length <= 10) {
                alert("Please ensure your contact number has 11 digits");
                jQuery("#pnumber").focus();
                jQueryflag = false;
                return false;
            }
            //alert(jQuery("#optin_tmp").is(":checked"));
            if (jQuery("#optin_tmp").is(":checked"))
                jQuery("#optin").val("Yes");
            else
                jQuery("#optin").val("No");
            //alert(jQuery("#optin").val());
        });
        if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {} else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {} else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
            if (navigator.userAgent.search("Macintosh") >= 0) {} else {}
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
            if (navigator.userAgent.search("Macintosh") >= 0) {} else if (navigator.userAgent.search("iPad") >= 0) {
                jQuery(".quicktext").css({ "width": "700px", "font-size": "8px" });
                jQuery(".container").css({ "padding-left": "0px" });
                jQuery("#footer").css({ "width": "1010px", "margin-left": "40px" });
                jQuery(".action_txt_fldbox").css({ "height": "40px" });

            } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("iPod") >= 0) {
                jQuery(".quicktext").css({ "width": "700px", "font-size": "8px" });
                jQuery(".container").css({ "padding-left": "40px" });
                jQuery("#footer").css({ "width": "1010px", "margin-left": "0px" });
                jQuery(".action_txt_fldbox").css({ "height": "40px" });

            } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("iPhone") >= 0) {
                jQuery(".quicktext").css({ "width": "680px", "font-size": "8px" });
                jQuery(".container").css({ "padding-left": "40px" });
                jQuery("#footer").css({ "width": "1010px", "margin-left": "0px" });
                jQuery(".action_txt_fldbox").css({ "height": "40px" });
            }
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {

        }

        jQuery('.showhide').click(function() {
            jQuery(this).children("p").slideToggle("slow");
            jQuery(this).children("div").toggleClass('textup');
        });
        jQuery("#findaddress").click(function() {
            /*jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: "false",
            url: "http://112.196.10.92/K-O/nationalpropertytrade/getpostalcode.php?zip=" + jQuery("#fldPostCode").val(),
            data: "",
            success: function(html) {
                if(html!="")
                {
                    var ar=html.split(";");
                    jQuery("#fldAddress").val(ar[0]);
                    jQuery("#fldTown").val(ar[1]);
                }
                else{
                    jQuery("#fldAddress").val("");
                    jQuery("#fldTown").val("");
                }
            }
        });*/

        });
        jQuery("#AddressStep2").submit(function() {
            if (jQuery("#fldFirstName").val() == "") {
                alert("First Name is required");
                jQuery("#fldFirstName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldLastName").val() == "") {
                alert("Last Name is required");
                jQuery("#fldLastName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val() == "") {
                alert("Contact Number is required");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false;
            } else if (isNaN(jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val())) {
                alert("Please enter only numbers for Contact Number");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false
            } else if (jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val().length < 11) {
                alert("Please ensure your Contact Number has 11 digits");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldEmailAddress").val() == "") {
                alert("Email Address is required");
                jQuery("#fldEmailAddress").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldAddress").val() == "") {
                alert("House No is required");
                jQuery("#fldAddress").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldPostCode").val() == "") {
                alert("Postcode is required");
                jQuery("#fldPostCode").focus();
                return false;
            }
        });
        jQuery("#AddressStep1").submit(function() {

            if (jQuery("#fldPostCode").val() == "") {
                alert("Postcode is required");
                jQuery("#fldPostCode").focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (jQuery("#fldAddress").val() == "") {
                alert("Address is required");
                jQuery("#fldAddress").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldTown").val() == "") {
                alert("City is required");
                jQuery("#fldTown").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldFirstName").val() == "") {
                alert("First Name is required");
                jQuery("#fldFirstName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldLastName").val() == "") {
                alert("Last Name is required");
                jQuery("#fldLastName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldEmailAddress").val() == "") {
                alert("Email Address is required");
                jQuery("#fldEmailAddress").focus();
                return false;
            } 
            if (jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val() == "") {
                alert("Contact Number is required");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false;
            } else if (isNaN(jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val())) {
                alert("Please enter only numbers for Contact Number");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false
            } else if (jQuery("#fldContactNumber").val().length < 11) {
                alert("Please ensure your Contact Number has 11 digits");
                jQuery("#fldContactNumber").focus();
                return false
            }
            if (jQuery("#fldPropertyValue").val() == "") {
                alert("Property Value is required");
                jQuery("#fldPropertyValue").focus();
                return false;
            }

          if(!jQuery('#gdpr').is(':checked')){ alert("Please check privacy policy agreement"); return false; }

            var property_value = removeCommas(document.getElementById("fldPropertyValue").value);
            property_value = formatAmount(property_value);
            if(property_value.length==2 || property_value.length==3){

                property_value = property_value + "000";
            }
            var percentage = 0.85;
            var AssistedTotal;
            var AssistedTotal2;
            var equity = 0;

            var cashoffer, cashofferperentage;
            var cashadvance, cashadvanceperentage;
            var assisted, assistedpercentage;
             var assisted2, assistedpercentage2;
            var upfront;



             if (property_value >= 0 && property_value <= 75000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.75;
                assistedpercentage = 0;
                 assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
            } else if (property_value >= 75001 && property_value <= 150000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.79;
                assistedpercentage = 0.85;
                assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.12;
            } else if (property_value >= 150001 && property_value <= 250000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.83;
                assistedpercentage = 0.85;
                assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.12;
            } else if (property_value >= 250001 && property_value <= 500000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.85;
                assistedpercentage = 0.90;
                 assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
            } else if (property_value >= 500001 && property_value <= 750000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.83;
                assistedpercentage = 0.85;
                 assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
              } else if (property_value >= 750001 && property_value <= 1000000) {
                cashofferperentage = 0.80;
                assistedpercentage = 0.83;
                 assisted2percentage = 0.95;
                cashadvanceperentage = 0.10;
            }


            cashoffer = property_value * cashofferperentage;
            assisted = property_value * assistedpercentage;
            assisted2 = property_value * assisted2percentage;
            cashadvance = property_value * cashadvanceperentage;


            document.getElementById("cashoffer").value = cashoffer;
            document.getElementById("AssistedTotal").value = assisted;
            document.getElementById("AssistedTotal2").value = assisted2;



            return true;

        });
        jQuery("#Postcode").submit(function() {
            if (jQuery("#fldPostCode").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter the postal code");
                jQuery("#fldPostCode").focus();
                return false
            }
        });
        jQuery("#AddressStep2").submit(function() {
            if (jQuery("#fldAlternativeContactNumber").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter the best contact number");
                //jQuery("#fldAlternativeContactNumber").focus(); 
                return false
            } else if (jQuery("#fldAlternativeContactNumber").val().length < 11) {
                alert("Please ensure your contact number has 11 digits");
                jQuery("#fldAlternativeContactNumber").focus();
                return false
            }
        });

        jQuery(".currency").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                var key = e.keyCode;

                if (!((key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                }
                }
        });
        jQuery('.currency').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
         });

        /*jQuery("#fldPropertyValue").keydown(function(e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        jQuery("#fldNumberofBedrooms").keydown(function(e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });


        jQuery("#fldOutstandingMortgage").keydown(function(e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        jQuery("#fldSecuredLoans").keydown(function(e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        jQuery("#fldContactNumber").keydown(function(e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });*/


    });


    function removeCommas(str) {
        str = str.replace(/,/g, '');
        str = str.replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
        return str;
    }

    function ValidateContact() {
        var id;
        id = document.getElementById("cfld1");
        if (id.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your name");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
        id = document.getElementById("cfld2");
        if (id.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter email address");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }

        id = document.getElementById("cfld3");
        if (id.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter the best contact number");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(id.value) || id.value.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            alert("Enter numeric value");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (id.value.length < 11) {
            alert("Please ensure your contact number has 11 digits");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
        id = document.getElementById("cfld4");
        if (id.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter subject");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    function formatAmount(input){
        input = input.trim();
        input = input.replace(".", "");
        input = input.replace(",", ""); 
        if(input.length==2 || input.length==3){
            input = input + "000";
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: Note that your `if` condition misses values. Eg. `80000.50`

Comment: Ideally I would like to hide the whole middle box if the property value is below 75000 on this page: https://www.nationalpropertytrade.co.uk/action2/

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you display the `property_value` value use the logical OR operator as a null coalescing operator, like this:

```
$('#yourOutputField').text(assisted || 'Not Available');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that - I'm quite new at this so please forgive my lack of knowledge on this. When the visitor to the site enters say 80000 this is the property_value and if they then select assisted - the property_value is multiplied by 0.00 give a result on another page as £0. Sorry if you already knew that by the code. - assisted = property_value * assistedpercentage; - I only want it for 80000 or less is entered for the property_value - I need help with where to put the code too. I can send you more of the js file if you need it? Thanks again.

Comment: Without seeing a more complete example of how this JS logic interacts with the UI we can't really help. If you want a working example, please include all relevant HTML and CSS in the question

Comment: I have added the full js file. It presents a result on a php file: <input type="text" name="pricetxt" class="price_txt" readonly value="<?php echo number_format($_POST['AssistedTotal']); ?>" />

Comment: The property value is collected here - https://www.nationalpropertytrade.co.uk/get-your-instant-cash-offer/

Comment: and the result is on this page: https://www.nationalpropertytrade.co.uk/action2/